# Assign ASCII character A-Z in a list

Tags: java

I need to fetch the characters from A-Z in ASCII and assign it to a string array or a list and loop through it. Any idea on how to fetch the ASCII characters and assign it to an array other than `String[] Asci=  {"A","B","C","D","E","F".....etc)`.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Am not finding anything. So only raised this ques. Thought of hardcoding it. but its not a good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List <String> ascii = new ArrayList <String> (26);

for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
    ascii.add (String.valueOf (c));
```

Comment: comma should be semi colon  - tx

Answer (score 1):

In Unicode (used with Java strings) characters from A to Z make a continuous sequence so using loop is possible. 'A' is, however, not the first Unicode character. It is possible to do this in generic way without assuming character codes and just assuming that A to Z is a sequence without other codes in between.

```
char values[] = new char['Z'-'A'];

int i = 0;
for (char c='A'; c<='Z'; c++)
  values[i++] = c;
```

Comment: should be `'Z' - 'A' + 1` -> 26 elements

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

It will store first 256 ascii characters

```
for (int i=0; i<256; i++){
  char temp = i;
  values[i] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String alpha[] = new String[26];
    for (char c = 65; c <= 90; c++)
    {
        alpha[c - 65] = String.valueOf(c);
    }

    for (String s : alpha)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this.....

```
public class Alphabet {
public Alphabet() {
for ( int i = 65; i < 91; i ++ ) {
System.out.println("Upper Case\n"+(char)i + " " + (char)(i+32));
}
}
public static void main(String [] args) {
new Alphabet();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using streams of Java 8 -

```
List<String> alphas = IntStream.range((int) 'A', (int) 'Z').boxed()
            .map(i -> Character.toString ((char) i.intValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```